# Change name in CGridView column

Tags: yii

I'm trying to change a column name of CGridView.

```
    <?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'package-days-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        'id',
        'package_id',
        'description',
        array(
            'name' => 'My description',
            'value' => 'description'
        ),
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
?>
```

**I need to add title 'My description' to 'description' column** but I'm getting this error

> Property "PackageDays.My description" is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you want change the header not the name try this way

'header'=>'My description',

```
<?php
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id' => 'package-days-grid',
'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
'filter' => $model,
'columns' => array(
    'id',
    'package_id',
    'description',
    array(
        'name' => 'description',
        'header' = => 'My Description',
        // 'value' => 'description' don't need no more
    ),
    array(
        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
```

));
?>